# import a project supposed to be ant builded to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, ant

Hi I'm trying to run the project I've downloaded from the official gwt - rpc - hibernate  - guide at http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html .

The guide suggest: "you can use Ant to build the project, as well as start up hosted mode to see the UI and our Hibernate instance setup in the embedded Jetty server." but I have to run it on eclipse.

My Question is : How can I import this guide project on eclipse? (the normal way: Import->Existing project into workspace, gives me error)

Answer (score 0):

Using the *New* > *Project* menu, you can select Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile wizard.

Comment: thank you !! Do you also know how can i run it as web application? because that option miss , there's no .war package and there's no server setted @E-Riz